# Can i access the variables of the python script after run that python script with console?

Tags: python-3.x, terminal

I run the python script using terminal command

```
python3 myScript.py
```

It's simply run my program but if i want to open python console after complete run of my script so that i can access my script's variables.

So, What should i do ? and How can i get my script's variables after run the code using terminal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the program run the other program you want with the variables as arguments. For example:

```
#program1
var1=7
var2="hi"
import os
os.system("python %s %d %s" % (filename, var1, var2))
```

---

```
#program2
import sys
#do something such as:
print(sys.argv[1]) #for var1
print(sys.argv[2]) #for var2
```

Basically, you are running program2 with arguments that can be referenced later.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open a python terminal (type 'python' in cmd);
2. Paste this (replace 'myScript.py' with your script filename):

```py
def run():
    t = ""
    with open('myScript.py') as f:
        t = f.read()
    return t
```

3. Type `exec(run())`. Now you will have access to the variables defined in myScript.py.

I needed to do this so I could explore the result of a request from the requests library, without having to paste the code to make the requests every time.